# How To control the position of -overlap div - with RESPONSIVE

Tags: html, css

here, with this code, the out put seems pretty , but when I resize the window the div **.grid-fourPictures** changes its position
I want to control the position of **.grid-fourPictures** over **#ContainerBackGround** with considering **responsive**

PS:
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0f/10/3e/0f103e27c99fe2ccb2b2073c50d1933b.png?fbclid=IwAR0NK5hBnLDNHv_WXvaEMuTX0Rz8qaHd41DqvGkWB6EdIiFoze2A2_5jBSk
this link explains what I mean , so the for pictures in the middle are **.grid-fourPictures** and the one under it is **#ContainerBackGround**

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <div class="backGroundAndGridContainer">


        <div id="ContainerBackGround"></div>/*1*/
            
    
    <div class="grid-fourPictures">/*2*/
    <div class="grid-firstPicture"></div>
    </div>


 </div>
```

css code

```
<style>
    .backGroundAndGridContainer{
           position: relative;
                               }

    .grid-fourPictures {
          position: absolute;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
          grid-gap: 10px;
          background-color: #2196F3;
          margin-left: 5%;
          margin-top: 25%;
          width: 90%;
          z-index: 10;
                              }
        
    #ContainerBackGround{
                        position: absolute;
                        text-align: center; 
                        max-width: 100%;
                        background-size:contain; 
                        width:100%;
                        height:500px;
                        overflow:hidden;
            
                      }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem when window is resized? With just that code I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you keep `camelCase`, `kebab-camelCase` and `PascalCase` in your ids and classes?

Comment: ok Mr.@Gunther this is good for me (https://ibb.co/GJtfDP6) and this is the problem (https://ibb.co/ChMgJPD)

Comment: @Gunther to make my code understood/readble.